# D3 Design re-usable component to accept parameter during "call"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This question is on d3 v5

I'm trying to create a re-usable component that accepts parameters. I'm unable to find the documentation / examples for syntax while building the component, that will help `call` the component with parameters.

For e.g. using native d3 brush, I'm able to achieve this:

```js
var data = [
  {id: 1, mv: [100,500]},
  {id: 2, mv: [300,600]},
  {id: 3, mv: [800,1000]}
];

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [1500, 90]]);
    
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate(0,"+i*100+")");
  
// able to pass a function parameter to brush.move
g.call(brush)
  .call(brush.move, (d,i)=>d.mv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=1500 height=1000></svg>
```

My question is: How can I write my component, so I can accept parameters similar to what is accepted in `brush.move`

This is what I came across in my searches:

- [Simple example of reusable d3 plugin](http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5073718) by cpbotha
- [Developing a D3.js Edge](http://backstopmedia.booktype.pro/developing-a-d3js-edge/3b-the-reusable-api/) book, specifically chapter 3, and the related code in [github](https://github.com/backstopmedia/D3Edge/tree/master/code/Chapter03/)

Unfortunately none deal with passing parameters similar to the `brush.move` above.

The current syntax of my component is similar to the Simple Example above.

```js
myorg.myelement = function() {
  // variables that can be set when constructing the function
  var height = "", maxwidth = "";

  function my(selection) {

    selection.each(function(d,i) {

      var elem = d3.select(this);
      // I have `this`, d and i
      // How can I get the param passed?
      ...
```

I'm looking for the syntax in my component to accept a parameter that has been passed during `call`

Thank you!

Comment: It's document for [`selection.call()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call): you can pass optional arguments to `.call()` which are than passed on to your function. Your code would be something like `function my(selection, param1, param2) {}`.

Comment: I realized the stupidity of the question a few mins ago. It's absurd. Of course it's documented! Thanks for taking the time to look into this and respond. I think it's better to delete the question

Comment: Don't chastise yourself too much—we see questions much worse than this each day. If you want to show public penance you might consider writing a well researched self-answer instead ;-)

Comment: Thank you :-) will do that shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as suggested by @altocumulus, as public penance I'm posting my own answer :-)

Of course, the documentation is very clear on how to `call` a function. Just pass the other params :-)

But here, I'll go one step further and create a blueprint for a reusable function that does accept function parameter and also makes use of the function, as I didn't find an example online. Being new to Javascript, I learnt several new things here including `apply` and `arguments`.

```js
// Here's my re-usable component

var myown = {};
myown.brush = function(){

  // setup variable
  var height = 0;
  
  function my(group){
    group.each(function(d,i){
      // here is the code for creating brush
      // note `this` is also available (in addition to d and i), for e.g.
      var b = d3.select(this);
      
      console.log("inside my each "+height);
      
    });
  }
  
  my.move = function (group, position){
    console.log("in move function");
    
    group.each(function(d,i){
      // here is the code for moving the brush
      // note `this` is also available (in addition to d and i), for e.g.
      var b = d3.select(this), that = this;
    
      console.log("inside move each");
      console.log(typeof(position));   // note it is function
      
      // now call that function
      // using "apply" and "arguments"
      let pos = position.apply(that, arguments);
      console.log(pos); 
    
    })
    
    return my;
  }
  
  my.height = function(value){
    if(!arguments.length) return value;
    height = +value;
    return my;
  }
  
  return my;
};

// Okay, now use all that nice code

var data = [
  {id: 1, mv: [100,500]},
  {id: 2, mv: [300,600]},
  {id: 3, mv: [800,1000]}
];

var brush = myown.brush().height(90);
    
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate(0,"+i*100+")");
  
g.call(brush).call(brush.move, (d,i)=>d.mv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=1500 height=1000></svg>
```